# Box plot not properly showing in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to recreate a boxplot in R using the `gapminder` dataset. I tried however it does not match with the output desired than what I get.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(gapminder) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(x = continent, y = gdpPercap),
    size = 0.7
  )
```

What I obtain:

[image: What I obtain]

Desired:

[image: Desired]

Comment: I think you need to change yaxis limit i..e `+ ylim(0, 50000)`

Comment: yep, I can reproduce it now.